# Removing duplicates elements with conditionality

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects that look like this:

```
[
    { project: "test1", date: "8/14/2018" },
    { project: "test1", date: "8/15/2018" },
    { project: "test2", date: "8/14/2018" }
]
```

I want to remove duplicate objects based on the project name, BUT, keep the one with the most recent date.

So my final array would like this:

```
[
    { project: "test1", date: "8/15/2018" },
    { project: "test2", date: "8/14/2018" }
]
```

I've come up with a disgruntled recursive solution that I'm unhappy with.

Looking for suggestions on a painless way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach I generally take for problems like this is to maintain a "dictionary" object to track uniqueness while iterating through, then extract the final result from that result. `reduce` is the go-to tool for creating one value from multiple values:

```
const dict = objects.reduce((result, item) => {
  const currentForProject = result[item.project];
  const isMostRecent = 
      !currentForProject
      || new Date(item.date) > new Date(currentForProject.date);
  if (isMostRecent) {
    result[item.project] = item;
  }
  return result;
}, {});

const mostRecents = Object.values(dict);
```

Answer (score 0):

I will propose the general algorithm to solve your task but the implementation is up to you.

- 1) sort the array based on `date` field;
- 2) create an empty `Set` for storing project names and empty array for the result;
- 3) iterate over the sorted array and check:
- 3.1) if the `Set` does not contain current project name, then:
- 3.2) add the project name to the `Set` and add current item to your result
  array;